# Powershell Remove numbers from excel column leaving text in place

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I would like to remove some numbers from a csv file in columns 1 and 2 but not 3.

Basically i'd i need to remove the six numbers and the - i.e. remove "000001 - "  and leave "OfficeFramework" from columns 1 and 2 but leave all other text.

the data i have in the excel csv file is:

```
Column1                     | Column2                       | Column3
000001 - OfficeFramework    | 002924 - Edition              | Standard
000001 - OfficeFramework    | 002925 - Install Type         | Server
000001 - OfficeFramework    | 002926 - Version              | v4.3.00
000001 - OfficeFramework    | 002927 - Audit Trail Enabled  | FALSE
```

I need it to look like:

```
Column1         | Column2               | Column3
OfficeFramework | Edition               | Standard
OfficeFramework | Install Type          | Server
OfficeFramework | Version               | v4.3.00
OfficeFramework | Audit Trail Enabled   | FALSE
```

So far i have:

```
get-content "H:\Compare\Results\test\servername_SystemInfo.csv" | 
    % { $_.split('*.-')[-1].trim()} | 
             set-content "H:\Compare\Results\test\new.csv"
```

but i get only two columns return as it deletes column 1 and returns:

```
newcolumn1          | newcolumn2 
Edition             | Standard
Install Type        | Server
0                   |
Audit Trail Enabled | FALSE
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to remove the number you can just use [-replace](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions#Example_-_The_-replace_Operator) like:

```
Get-Content yourFileName.csv | % { $_ -replace '\d*\s-\s', '' } | Set-Content yourFileName2.csv
```

Or, if it always going to be 6 digits you could replace the `*` with `{6}`

Comment: will this work if the number is a variable like in column 2?

Comment: This just removes every instance of digits followed by ` - ` in the string - so it should. However, I don't know what your referring by *a variable like in column 2*.

Comment: I meant as in my example of data i have in column 2 it has different starting numbers i.e. 002924, 002925 etc. That being said i have tried your code with the {6} instead of the * and this does what i need it to do, Thanks for your help really appriciated.

Comment: You should be able to use `'\d*\s-\s'` as well as `'\d{6}\s-\s'` the only difference in the two is the first one looks for any amount of digits until a `-` is found, and the latter strictly looks for 6 digits followed by a `-`.